# Need Help in maintaining session in PHP Curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I want to grab images from http://www.ps3-themes.com/, but whenever i directly enter image URL it doesn't work. It redirects it to main URL of site. I'm using following code.

```
$cookie_file = 'c:/tmp-cookie.txt';
$crl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ps3-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/11414-FordF150RaptorSVT.jpg");
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$html = curl_exec($crl);

if (file_exists($cookie_file)) {
print 'Created cookie file ' . $cookie_file;
} else {
print 'Could not create cookie file ' . $cookie_file;
}
```

I can say it requires maintaining session but not sure how to do that.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, this isn't a cookie issue but a referrer issue — attempting to display the image from anywhere but the site itself will redirect to the site home instead. This is usually done to prevent hotlinking, which is a bandwidth annoyance.

You can work around this by setting your cURL HTTP referrer to an appropriate URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before you make the CURL request.

Answer (score 0):

1st you try to open the image directly in browser. It does not open up. May be the image is not there or authorization is needed.

Comment: http://www.ps3-themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/11414-FordF150RaptorSVT.jpg, this image link goes to site's home page. But if you open home page and then open this image, it works.